# How to get indivisual Id data in JsonObject in Android using retrofit libary

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I am new at Android platform. getting tired to get data using **Retrofit** from like this link
I want to use that link as Indivisual ID data which is like 1,2,3,... 
I have try so many times but it shows Empty...!!! **no data are coming**

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1

> My Api interfatce Class is like

```
String BaseURL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/"; //return Jsone Array

    String id = "1";

    @GET(id)
    Call<List<patientsJson>> getPatientsJson();
```

the id value will be change every time and come from different button from another Activity class.

> My patients_Activity Class

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Api.BaseURL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);

        Call<List<patientsJson>> call = api.getPatientsJson();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<patientsJson>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<patientsJson>> call, Response<List<patientsJson>> response) {
                List<patientsJson> patientsJsons = response.body();

                for (patientsJson data: patientsJsons ){

                    t1.setText(data.getName());
                    t2.setText(data.getId());
                    t3.setText(data.getEmail());

                    Log.d("Name: ", data.getName() );
                    //Log.d("ID: ", data.getId());
                    Log.d("Email: ", data.getEmail());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<patientsJson>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
```

> My MainActivity Class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, patients_Activity.class);
            //intent.putExtra("ID", "1");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

> My patientsJson class is

```
  //private String postId;
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String email;

    public patientsJson( String id, String name, String email) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }


    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass id dynamically from code.You just need to write retrofit interface for

```
@GET("{id}")
Call<List<patientsJson>> getPatientsJson(@Path("id") int id);
```

Now when calling the web service you need to pass ID as a parameter.

Comment: Hi @Kirtan got Error Like this........ expected begin_array but was begin_object at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: @hamzarahman that error is not related to retrofit. Its how you parse the JSON data in response.As per response of the web service, it's returning JSON Object where you have written JSON Array in response.

Comment: So, how can I get rid of it ? as far I understand Retrofit work with Json Array not object. but I need to work with only objects.. So when I pass this id it return a JsonObject.. is it like that?

Comment: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1 this URL is returning Object as you can see it.And it's not like that retrofit is only working with arrays.

Comment: can you please give the solution how it will work.. I need only one id data not all ..I am totally frustrated Right now..